# Fade in up animation on scroll (but only once) considering seo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, seo

I need to achieve this animation kind of effect, which is used for example in [this](http://www.hugoboss.com/uk/fashionguides/menswear-guide-how-to-fold-a-pocket-square/fs-story-163jbl26kakh7.html?fdid=fashionguides&csortb1=published&csortd1=2) page. 
I have tried many times everything I found on internet but none of them solutions worked like this and I was not able to fix it. I suppose it should be easy for anyone who knows Javascript (but I am not one of them guys and this is the first time I needed something like this and my research lasted a more then a few hours, so I am sorry, but I tried to ask more JS experienced guys).

In ideal case it should not be solved via hidden stuff as I am afraid of bad effects for SEO.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){
    
        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){
            
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window+500 > bottom_of_object ){
                
                $(this).addClass("slideUp");
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'});
                    
            }
            
        }); 
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
.slideUp{
 animation-name: slideUp;
 -webkit-animation-name: slideUp; 

 animation-duration: 0.5s; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;

 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  
 
}

@keyframes slideUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(5%);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
 }
    100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
 }
 
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5%);
        -webkit-display: none;
        -webkit-opacity: 0;
 }
 100%{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
        -webkit-display: block;
        -webkit-opacity: 1;
 }   
}

.red-bg {background-color: red; color: white; padding: 50px; margin-top: 25px;}
.blue-bg {background-color: blue; color: white; padding: 50px; margin-top: 25px;}

.hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideme red-bg">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme blue-bg">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
</div>
<div class="hideme red-bg">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet sit veroeros sed et blandit consequat sed veroeros lorem et blandit adipiscing feugiat phasellus tempus hendrerit, tortor vitae mattis tempor, sapien sem feugiat sapien, id suscipit magna felis nec elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
</div>
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Can you add the code you have to the question?  Check out [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @TimHutchison the closest I get is this: https://jsfiddle.net/g2wLgz7c/ (I made a little progress after I asked, but still I think my code is a bit messy and I am worried about opacity:0; because of SEO). So if anybody could post an easy solution with pure code without messy stuff, that would be so nice :)

Comment: I added your code to the question itself (you may have to wait until the edit is peer reviewed before it is visible).  Please add code to your question like this in the future.  jsfiddle is nice, but if the link goes away, then the value of your question decreases significantly because we don't have the code

Comment: @mdblzk Your code seems very similar to the desired effect. What else is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Right, so if I understand this correctly, you need this to only be faded if its not on the screen currently. This is the javascript you would need for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function fading() {

    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1000);

        }

    });

}

fading();

$(window).scroll( function(){
    fading();
});

});
```

I have attached the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/7105/

In addition, if its the `opacity: 0;` you're worried about, you can ignore all of the above and just add a white gradient with a high `z-index` fixed to the bottom of your page. This may cause a few issues if you have buttons on your page so if you went down this route, give it a small height.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, but as I mentioned, I am afraid of "opacity: 0" (because of SEO). Is there any other solution then setting 0 opacity? I need the animation to fade in a move up a little bit. Moving up is easy
----
@keyframes slideUp {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(5%);
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
 }
    100% {
  transform: translateY(0%);
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
 }
 
}
----

But opacity 0 does not work here... And as I said, could it be done without it?

Comment: If you're really that worried about it, you could always add a faded div fixed to the bottom of the page with the highest z-index. That also creates a fading effect and no javascript needed

Comment: I suppose that Google would not be happy about this solution nether. But thank you for another perspective. I suppose that there is not any "cleaner" solution then 0 to 1 opacity or faded div for the "fade in" animation?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of would be to add an absolute div on top of the one you want to fade and just animate the background opacity on it from white to 0. Theres a few ways of looking at it I guess, nothing I'd consider 'clean' though :D